# How to Change the Height and Width Filter in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, styles

I need to change the Height and width of the filter by slider range . 
How can i change it?.

In broad,
My height and width are shows like :

```
Height :
1.5 (4)
99.8 (300)
....
...

Width :
56 (555)
90 (4545)
....
...
```

I want this in a slider, How to Change it in Slider range or give me a hint to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need extension for this ??

Comment: there is no free extension to do this..So, I am looking for manual programming solution.

Comment: Directly there is no extension But I will Give you the trick with the help of that you can achieve this

Comment: Can you please tell what's the trick?

Comment: Wait I will Put as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some free extensions are available,

What you have to do is create a new attribute for height and width.

That attribute should be `price` because layered navigation works only on `price`, `select` and `multiselect`.

If you install any of the below extension that will create checkbox for other option and show slider for `price` attribute type.

> I am suggesting Extension on OP request.

https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

Comment: Catalog Input Type for Store Owner  = price . I think it display $ also in frontend. Is this a good option for height and weight?

Comment: after that just debug the extension and put some condition, I think you are able to do that

Comment: ok i am trying now. Thankyou :)

Comment: All above extension is not working in magento 1.9.2

Comment: FME extension I am using in 1.9.2.4 perfectly, check conflicts with your theme

Comment: Do i need to configure some files related to catalog search after installing this extensions?

Comment: I think layered navigation not working in search google it for more detail